# CCA2-secure encryption based on LWE/Ring-LWE

Tags: chosen-ciphertext-attack, lwe

As I understand it, cryptosystems based on LWE/Ring-LWE are typically only IND-CPA, and fail to satisfy IND-CCA2.  In fact, it appears that chosen ciphertext attacks could allow secret key recovery (!).

What is the best known IND-CCA2 secure encryption algorithm based on (Ring-)LWE?  What about key exchange?

Comment: I think that having homomorphic properties precludes the ability to have IND-CCA2 status in general; I wish I had a better reference then [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/16468/29554), but I can't seem to find one right now.

Comment: @EllaRose I know.  I don't need or want homomorphic properties.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind relying on random oracles, the simplest approach is to apply a generic transformation such as Fujisaki-Okamoto to the (Ring-)LWE based scheme you start from. See for example Peikert's [PQCrypto'14 paper](https://web.eecs.umich.edu/~cpeikert/pubs/suite.pdf) for a concrete instantiation, and the [TCC 2016 paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/1210) of Targhi and Unruh for a proof of security of this type of transform in the quantum random oracle model.

Lattice-based CCA2-secure encryption in the standard model is usually obtained using lattice trapdoors. The state-of-the-art construction is due to Micciancio and Peikert (section 6.3 of this [EUROCRYPT 2012 paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2011/501)).